# Font editor widget in Qt

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt-creator

`Qt Creator` provides an editor for setting `QLable` style (`CSS` for label font style primarily): [image]

I would like to do the same thing in my `Qt` application: be able to call a Qt component/system font editor with a font style argument passed and get a new style when a user finishes editing(2).

Simplified code:

```
Qlabel qlabel;
QFontEditor fontEditor;
fontEditor.setFontStyle(qlabel.getStyle());
fontEditor.show();
qlabel.setStyle(fontEditor.getStyle());
```

I wonder if there is anything in `Qt` that can be used as I have spent two days looking for a component. The only one I have spotted is the one really used in `Qt Creator` project but it seems to be hard to incorporate to my application:

> https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/51bb52139c479cca2dae82eb08aeb8d04718fca1/src/plugins/texteditor/fontsettings.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QFontDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdialog.html) class provides a dialog widget for selecting a font.

```
bool ok;
QFont font = QFontDialog::getFont(&ok);
```